# Store mysql deadlocks

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I was wondering if there is a way of storing every transaction that causes a deadlock in a mysql database in a seperate table the moment it is recorded in the innodb?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

In version 5.5.30, `innodb_print_all_deadlocks` became available.  Set it to `ON`, but be aware that the log file (probably `error.log`) that it uses may clutter disk.

Techniques for *diminishing* the number of deadlocks:

- Speed up the transactions.
- Move DML statements out of a transaction (whey it is OK to do so).
- If there is an `IN` or `OR` in some statement (eg `DELETEing` several rows), sort them.

The last one *may* turn a deadlock into a "locK_wait_timeout", wherein one of the transactions is silently stalled until the other finishes.